# elixir mix app cannot understand clearly

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

i try to work with elixir.

it's bit hard to understand about application.ex

```
defmodule PluralsightTweet.Application do
  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: PluralsightTweet.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
       worker(PluralsightTweet.TweetServer, [])
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: PluralsightTweet.Supervisor]
    process = Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
    PluralsightTweet.Scheduler.schedule_file("* * * * *", Path.join("#{:code.priv_dir(:pluralsight_tweet)}",
    "sample.txt"))
    process
  end
end
```

i'm following pluralsight elixir tutorial 
this is scheduler to tweet text in every minute from reading text file

task is success but doesn't have crystal clear ideal about the process

can some one please explain whats happening inside application.ex
run as a supervisor app

Comment: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/supervisor-and-application.html and https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `use Application`

This line means the current module is the entrance of an application. Such module can be configured in the `mix.exs` to be started as a unit.

```
# Inside mix.exs
def application do
  [
    extra_applications: [:logger],
    mod: {PluralsightTweet.Application, []}  # <-- this line
  ]
end
```

#### The `start` function

This function is the callback when the application starts up. You can consider it as the `main` function in some other languages.

#### `import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false`

It just lets you omit the module name when you call `worker`, `supervisor` and `supervise`. The `warn: false` part suppresses warning even if you don't call any of those functions.

#### `children = [worker(PluralsightTweet.TweetServer, [])]`

This line specifies the child processes that your application supervises. Note that at this point, the child processes are not spawned yet.

The `worker(mod, args)` just defines a worker spec that will be started later. The `args` will be passed to the `mod`'s `start_link` function when starting the worker.

#### `opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: PluralsightTweet.Supervisor]`

The supervisor options.

See [strategies documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-strategies) for the meaning of `strategy: :one_for_one` and other strategies.

Since you have only one worker, all strategies except `:simple_one_for_one` works pretty the same.

The tricky part is `name: PluralsightTweet.Supervisor`. You may wonder where did the module `PluralsightTweet.Supervisor` come from. The fact is that it is NOT a module. It's only an atom `:"Elixir.PluralsightTweet.Supervisor"`, which serves as the name of the supervisor process.

#### `Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)`

Now the supervisor process and its child processes are spawned.